# Package 'com.class.xxx.test' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'class' is a Java keyword

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, keyword, package-name

I am new to espresso testing in android. When I try to build test apk I am getting this error:

```
Package 'com.class.xxx.test' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'class' is a Java keyword.
```

Is there any possible way to change the package name in the test build config or any other solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this because I had a package name with a `-` in it (i.e. `test-support`). In the module's `AndroidManifest.xml` I had

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thomas.myapp.test-support" />`

The [Java Language Spec](https://web.archive.org/web/20090201061750/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html) says

> If the domain name contains a hyphen, or any other special character not allowed in an identifier (§3.8), convert it into an underscore.

I didn't convert to an underscore, but just removing the hyphen works. I changed the `AndroidManifest.xml` to

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thomas.myapp.testsupport" />`

and it works fine now. [Khemraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476384/270847) put me on the right track to figuring this out.

Answer (score 3):

As simple as it say.

> not a valid Java package name, 'class' is a Java keyword.

There are some reserve keywords in `Java`. Which you can not use. You are using **`class`**, which is reserved word.

**You can change class package name as solution.**

[List of Java reserved keywords.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords)

Comment: I need to change the package name only on build for test apk do you maybe know how to do that?

Comment: Just use name refracting, select package to rename (class), then press shift + F6 to rename refract. It will handle all imports automatically.

Comment: Yes but it is auto generated and when I change it it gets back to old one on build...

Comment: You can not change only test package name. I think, Change app package name, you need not change `build.gradle` package name, just use refracting in your `manifest.xml` package name.